# Repeating program help?

Tags: java, loops

Ok so I'm at another impasse with my program. I need it to repeat, yet I do not understand what I'm reading in the text on how to do it. It only covers repeating values, like a gradebook program. Anyway, I need the program to keep repeating until the user inputs "stop" as the employee name.This is my code so far:

package payroll_program_2;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
    public class payroll_program_2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        float hours;                                           
        float rate;                                              
        String name;
        float total_pay;


    System.out.println("Please enter employee name");       
        name = input.nextLine();
            if("stop".equals(name))
            { return;
            }

    System.out.println("Please enter hourly rate");             
        rate = input.nextFloat();                               
        if (rate <0)                                             
            {                                                     
                System.out.println("Pay rate cannot be negative");
                System.out.println("Please enter hourly rate");
                rate = input.nextFloat();
            }
    System.out.println("Please enter hours worked");            
        hours = input.nextFloat();                               
         if (hours <0)
            {
                System.out.println("Hours cannot be negative");
                System.out.println("Please enter hours worked");
                hours = input.nextFloat();
            }
    System.out.println("Employee's total pay for this week");  
        total_pay = hours*rate;                                   

    System.out.printf("The total pay for %s is $%.2f\n", name, total_pay);        


        }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while (true) {...}
```

Comment: this was it. so simple, yet I didn't get it from the book. Thanks you guys :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `while` loop or `for` loop, as in:

```
while (true) {
   // .. read some input ...
   if ( /* input is "stop" */ ) {
      break; // this causes the loop to exit
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply include:

while(true)
{

}

around your code, and for each input say.

if ("stop".equals(input))
  break;

Comment: im trying the do - while loop, but i wanted some input from smarter people than me lol. im brand new and know nothing. and its really hard to learn this from a book...

Answer (score 0):

The break idea will work fine, but another way to do it would be to wrap the entire thing in a

`while(! name.equals("stop")){...}`

and everything after the name input in a similar if statement

```
(if(! name.equals("stop"))){...}
```

so that it will not execute.  Breaking out of the loop is probably easier all around, but I know that there are some people out there who frown on using break statements.

Answer (score 0):

you should have the following while statement

**hasNextLine()** method checks anymore line needs to be read from stdin.

```
while ( input.hasNextLine() )
{

     // your code goes here
}
```